# When using Guice, is it possible to get an object that was bound in a module?

Tags: guice

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Helper.class).toProvider(HelperProvider.class);
        ServiceInterceptor serviceInterceptor = new ServiceInterceptor(manager);
        bindInterceptor(annotatedWith(With.class), annotatedWith(ServiceName.class), serviceInterceptor);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Manager manager(final Helper helper) {
       Manager manager = new DefaultManager(helper);
       return manager;
    }
}
```

Basically, my problem is that I need the manager instance to create the serviceInterceptor instance, and I need serviceInterceptor in the bindInterceptor. I'm very new to Guice, so I feel like this is something simple that I'm not able to find a workaround for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be solved by requesting injection for your object instance. Consider this example I wrote up:

```
public class TestModule2 extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Helper.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(Manager.class).to(ManagerImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);

        MyInterceptor i = new MyInterceptor();
        requestInjection(i); // intercept the thing

        bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.any(), i);
    }

    public static interface Manager {
        public void talk();
    }

    public static class ManagerImpl implements Manager {

        @Inject
        public ManagerImpl(Helper h) {
        }

        @Override
        public void talk() {
            System.out.println("talking");
        }
    }

    public static class Helper {

    }

    public static class MyInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

        @Inject
        private Manager m;

        public MyInterceptor() {
        }

        @Override
        public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("intercept and manager " + m.getClass().getName());
            return invocation.proceed();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector createInjector = Guice.createInjector(new TestModule2());
        Manager instance = createInjector.getInstance(Manager.class);
        instance.talk();
    }
}
```

To explain:

1. I bind all my instances first the normal way. This will be Helper and Manager. Manager can be injected with helper and so on. Do not forget the inject annotations.
2. I create my interceptor method. Now i need this to be injected. Guice has a method for that scenario:

   ```
   MyInterceptor i = new MyInterceptor();
   requestInjection(i); // inject the thing
   ```

This now puts the Manager instance into your interceptor.

And finally, when I run the above code, I get:

```
intercept and manager test.guice.TestModule2$ManagerImpl$$EnhancerByGuice$$e5e270bc
talking
```

Note that the interceptor is printing its message, then the method call gets executed.

I hope that helps,

Artur